# -다 하다 grammar in Korean dialogue

Tags: grammar, verb

I have noticed this grammar pattern, in the following sentences, in episode 13 of Under the Queen's umbrella:

> 시신을 보지 못했**다 하옵니다**

> She did not see the corpse [lit: they-said they failed to see the corpse]

And:

> 누구를 찾았**다 하셨사옵니까**?

> Whom did you say you found ?

My conclusions:

1. Conveys what the speaker or person referred-to said
2. Convey a degree of certainty
3. Is formal speech [since in both positions the utterances were by people in servile positions to the listener]

***Am I correct ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right. 다 하다 is short for 다고 하다 and this to sum up your observations and to put it simply means **it's said to be**.

> 그렇다(고) 합니다. It's said to be that's the case.

> 그렇지 않다(고) 합니다. It's said to be that's not the case.

> 그랬다(고) 합니다. It's said to be that was the case.

It's important to note that **only a verb** can precede 다(고) 하다. But should it be a **noun** and not a verb then 다(고) 하다 becomes 라(고) 하다 or 이라(고) 하다 if the last syllable in the noun ends with a consonant.

> 공짜라(고) 합니다. It's said to be free.

> 좋은 사람이라(고) 합니다. He/she's said to be a good person.

> 부자라(고) 합니다. He/she's said to be rich.

> 그리 할 것이라(고) 합니다. It's said to be done that way.

I'd like to mention though semantics-wise 라고 하다 can also mean **it's been asked of/to** as a means of command.

> 앉으라고 합니다. It's asked of you to sit.

> 그리 하라(고) 합니다. It's asked to be done that way.